# DataTrigger change according to AttachedProperty value

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, attached-properties

I am trying to change the background property in DataTemplate according to AttachedProperty value of the element,
I don't get any binding errors but the Background field stay with its default value.
What is the prorblem?

View:

```
<ContentControl common:IsOpen={Binding IsOpenValue} ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
  <Border Width="20" Height="20" Name="TheName"/>

  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (common:IsOpen), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=common:IsOpenEnum.Open>
      <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TheName" Value="Red"/>
   </DataTrigger>

   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (common:IsOpen), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=common:IsOpenEnum.Closed>
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="TheName" Value="Green"/>
   </DataTrigger>

  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here:

You have to use the full syntax when binding to attached properties. Something like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(common:IsOpen), Rela....
```

Next, using `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` will probably give you the `ContentPresenter` that is in the control template of the `ContentControl`, when you are actually looking for the property on the `ContentControl`. Instead, use

```
....RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}...
```

Lastly, for brevity, drop `common:IsOpenEnum.` from the value. Use just the value of the enum:

```
....Value="Open">
```

[I believe the lack of quotations for the value is a glitch here and that they do appear in real code]